# How can I optimize my code using batch operations?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to perform a basic multiplication on a range of values in my spreadsheet, and then divide those values by a range of values from a column, note that my range is 8 columns long and my division range is one column long.

I have this code:

```
function multiply() {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("1iXQxyL3URe1X1FgbZ76mEFAxLnxegyDzXOMF6WQ5Yqs"));
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("json");
  var sheet2 = doc.getSheetByName("tabla de frecuencias");
  var sheet3 = doc.getSheetByName("Template");

  var range = sheet2.getDataRange();
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var numCols = range.getNumColumns()-1; //This will get the division values which are located in the last column
  var targ =  sheet2.getLastColumn();

  for (var i = 2; i <= numRows; i++) {
    for (var j = 2; j <= numCols; j++) {
      var A = range.getCell(i,j).getValue();
      var value = A;
      for (var v = 1; v <= numRows; v++) {

        var T = range.getCell(v,targ).getValue();

        range.getCell(i,j).setValue(value*100/T);
      }
    }         
  }
}
```

It's very slow, it reads and writes on each cell from a sheet where I have numeric values ready to be multiplied by 100 and divided by a value located in a single column, this value is different for each row.

My script gets the job done extremly slowly, batch operations appear promising, if that's not the best solution, I will accept any other alternate solution regardless of the question title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what your looking for.

```
function multiply() 
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet60");
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var dataA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=1;i<dataA.length;i++) 
  {
    for(var j=1;j<dataA[0].length-1;j++) 
    {
      var value=dataA[i][j];
      for (var v=1;v<dataA.length;v++) 
      {
        var T=dataA[v][dataA[0].length-1];//the value in the last column on this row
        Logger.log('v=%s dataA[%s][%s]=%s',v,i,j,dataA[i][j]);
        dataA[i][j]=value * 100 / T;//This seems wrong because it puts a different value into dataA[i][j] which doesn't change inside this inner loop and so only the last value remains in dataA[i][j]
      }
    }         
  }
  rg.setValues(dataA);
}
```

Try to minimize the use of getValue and replace with one getValues to get all values in two dimensional array.  Then setValues all at one time at the end of the loop.

Okay made another change. Getting more reasonable results.

[image]

I'm beginning to think that you may not actually want the v loop at all.  Take a look at this one and look at the Logger.  We just write the data once.

```
function percentages() 
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet60");
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var dataA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=1;i<dataA.length;i++) 
  {
    for(var j=1;j<dataA[0].length-1;j++) 
    {
      var value=dataA[i][j];
      var T=dataA[i][dataA[0].length-1];
      dataA[i][j]=value * 100 / T;
      Logger.log('dataA[%s][%s]=%s',i,j,dataA[i][j]);
    }         
  }
  rg.setValues(dataA);
}
```

This is the output for this version.

[image]

Comment: I have tried your script with no success, would you comment each line to aid in an explanation for me to understand?

Comment: I just made a change to the second loop so it won't be accessing data in the last column.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bXvoWn8yocYDyJJpU-hiGBj1kRgEoQx7GXDP4Q3q9sg/edit?usp=sharing Nothing happens to my spreadsheet as I run the adapted script. I want to multiply each of those values times 100 and divide by the number in the total column

Comment: Your script is great maybe I have not been clear on the operation that I want it to do: For example; B2 should be multiplied by 100 then divided by the value on row H2 in your example (to get percentages) I don't understand what calculation the script is doing, the result should be for example 50 if the value in the cell is 5.

Comment: I made another change and now I think I'm closer to what your your function was doing.

Comment: I think I still have something wrong in the algorithm.  Take a look at the logger you'll see that dataA[i][j] gets a value for each row but only the last one remains.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for being the correct answer!