# google script too slow, is there a way to speed it up?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that has been a labour of love, its taken me a while to figure out, but now that I have it working, when using it on a test sheet with a small amount of data it works perfectly without issues.

The issue comes when using it on a live sheet with over 40,000 rows of data, the script simply can not finish within the 30 minutes allowed.

As I am pretty new to script I wonder if I have somehow made my script needlessly long.

I have pasted my script below, but let me explain what I am trying to achieve.

each customer would have their own sales report, and because of privacy they need to be on separate sheets.
So I have my MasterData sheet and another sheet I named URL's
within URL's I have a table that contains the customer name and the ID of their spreadsheet.

What my script achieves is to Filter my MasterData by customer name, copy all the data that is visible and then paste it in the customer's individual spreadsheet taking the ID from the URL's sheet.

It has taken me quite a while to get to this point so I am hoping there is a way I can speed this up.

```
function get_data(){
  var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MasterSheet");
  var s3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("URL's")
    var range = s1.getRange(1, 1, s1.getLastRow(), s1.getLastColumn())
  var filter = range.getFilter() || range.createFilter();
  var foo_index = 2; // column A
  

  var data = []
  for (var j = 1;j<s3.getLastRow(); j++){
   var filterName = s3.getRange(j+1, 1).getValue()
   var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextEqualTo(filterName).build();
  var values = s1.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(1, criteria)
   var id = s3.getRange(j+1,2).getValue()
   var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName("MasterSheet")
   var clear = s2.getRange(2,1,s2.getLastRow(),s2.getLastColumn()).clear({contentsOnly: true})
   var data = []
   for (var i = 1; i < s1.getLastRow(); i++){
    if(!s1.isRowHiddenByFilter(i+1)) {
      var row_data = s1.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, s1.getLastColumn()).getValues()
      data.push(row_data[0])
    }
   }
   var paste = s2.getRange(s2.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,25).setValues(data)
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that for your case [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a more suitable place, as this is not even a question on your part. Only thing that I could tell you right away is that the use of `s2` is completly useless when you already have the sheet at `s1`.

Comment: I agree with @Raserhin. The major boost of performance you will get if you get rid of `getRange.getValue` statements in the for loop and use `getValues` outside of the for loop and work with the arrays instead. I just randomly found an example to show you what I mean by that: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46679343/how-can-i-optimize-my-code-using-batch-operations)

Answer (score 0):

I had to make some guesses about header names but if you'll go through this code as well as I tried to go through your code then I think you will come up with a faster solution.

```
function get_data() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const s1 = ss.getSheetByName("MasterSheet");
  const s3 = ss.getSheetByName("URL's");
  const [mhA, ...mdata]=s1.getDataRange().getValues();
  const [chA, ...cdata]=s3.getDataRange().getValues();
  let midx = {};//index fo mastersheet by column name
  let cidx = {};//index to url's sheet by column name
  mhA.forEach((h, i) => { midx[h] == i });
  chA.forEach((h, i) => { cidx[h] == i });
  
  cdata.forEach((cr,i)=>{
    let data = [];
    let cname=cr[cidx['CustomerName']];//I dont really know what you have in s3 for headers so I guessed
    let cssid=cr[cidx['ID']];
    mdata.forEach((mr,j)=>{
      if(mr[midx['CustomerName']]=cname) {//if customer name from s3 matches customer from s1 the save that row in data
        data.push(mr);
      }
    });
    let css=SpreadsheetApp.openById(cssid);
    let csh=css.getSheetByName("MasterSheet");
    csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);// put all rows into customer mastersheet
  });
}
```